# Drop down list issue when using VoiceOver on Mac or Google TalkBack on Android

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover, talkback

I have seen this issue in many sites such as the [Facebook Registration](https://www.facebook.com/)
Birthday dropdown lists or even [WebAim Accessible Forms](https://webaim.org/techniques/forms/controls). The problem is the following:

By using the screen reader I focus on a drop down list and select an element. After that, I try to leave the drop down element and move focus on the next element (by ctrl + alt + right arrow in VoiceOver or by Swiping right on Android). When I do this, instead of the focus moving to the next element, the screen reader announces the next element in the drop down list(although I have selected it and the list is now closed) and not the next element after the drop down list. This results in me getting stuck there and not being able to continue.

- Am I doing something wrong there while controlling the screen reader?
- Is there something that could change in the code of the sites I mentioned in order for this to be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You can try giving it:

- a `tab-index` of -1 when hidden
- or an `aria-hidden=true` when the list is not in view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow.  I tried the WebAIM example with VoiceOver on an iPhone and with NVDA in Firefox.

On the iPhone, a `<select>/<option>` list displays the dropdown contents in a separate 'dialog' looking thing at the bottom of the display.  You have to navigate to the 'done' button to close the dialog.  After that, swiping left/right goes to the next thing on the page.

With NVDA on Firefox, I can use the up/down arrow keys to change the value, or I can use alt+down arrow to expand the list, then arrow up/down to my choice and either hit Enter or tab off the list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
1) I am talking about VoiceOver on a Mac and not an iPhone.
2) On NVDA it just runs fine. The problem is on VoiceOver for Mac and GoogleTalkBack for Android. Try it with these and you will have the issue I am describing.

Answer (score 0):

I too have experienced this problem when testing MacOS Voiceover in conjunction with Google Chrome.  The Select Menu became a "trap" from which I could not escape.  However, this was not the case for using Voiceover with Safari.  I'm now convinced that if I want to get reasonable behavior from Voiceover, it should be used only with Safari.